# Sacar MIN y MAX con php

Tags: php, mysql

Requiero sacar el mínimo de un campo en MySQL que hago SUM() al mismo con PHP, por ejemplo:
Mi campo se llama carne, utilizo SUM() para sumar toda esa columna, hasta ahí todo bien obtengo la sumatoria de toda la columna, ahora bien como puedo sacar el mínimo de esa misma columna o campo.
Quisiera poder obtener ese resultado y colocarlo en campo

Comment: Por favor trata de proveer un mejor contexto a tu pregunta pues la misma no es clara, lee sobre un [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería de la siguiente forma, tomando en cuenta que el tipo de dato de tu columna es DOUBLE:

```
SELECT MIN(carne) AS minimo, SUM(carne) AS sum FROM tabla
```

El resultado será algo similar a:

```
minimo   | suma
---------------------
1.23456  | 14.845172
```

En una respuesta comentaste que te arroja 0 en el MIN, posiblemente hay un campo con 0.

Comment: `WHERE carne > 0` eliminaría los registros que accidentalmente tenga el valor `0` y que no deben ser considerados.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql tiene funciones para el mínimo y máximo, tienes que editar tu consulta y usando las funciones Min() y Max().

```
SELECT MIN(Carne) AS MinimoCarne
FROM Productos;
```

Puedes leer más sobre Min y Max en mysql en:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero ya lo intente así y me arroja 0, es una columna con formato DOUBLE y se va añadiendo cantidades día tras día...